# How to prevent pathlib’s Path.glob from returning files when the glob ends in a slash?

Tags: python, pathlib

The the new `Path.glob` from `pathlib` seems to behave differently from the old `glob.glob` when the glob pattern ends in a slash it seems.

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: from glob import glob

In [3]: glob('webroot/*/')
Out[3]: ['webroot/2017-06-07/']

In [4]: list(Path().glob('webroot/*/'))
Out[4]: 
[PosixPath('webroot/.keep'),
 PosixPath('webroot/2017-06-07'),
 PosixPath('webroot/matches.2017-06-07.json')]
```

Is that by design, some compatibility issue I haven’t encountered? And is there a way to stop it from doing that?

For now I’ll work around it with:

```
[path for path in Path().glob('webroot/*/') if path.is_dir()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open bug about this:

- https://bugs.python.org/issue22276

No resolution yet.

Your workaround looks fine, although if you don't mind also including the 'webroot' directory itself you may prefer using a `**` glob:

```
>>> list(Path('webroot').glob('**'))
[PosixPath('webroot'), PosixPath('webroot/2017-06-07')]
```