# Glob and pathlib Path.glob yield different results for same pattern

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I'm trying to iterate over all directories (not recursively) inside a given directory. I have this file structure:

```
debian/
dev-requirements.txt
MANIFEST.in
mypy.ini
pytest.ini
README.md
requirements.txt
resources/
reviewer/
setup.py*
tests/
tox.ini
```

If i use `glob.glob`, it's yielding the correct results:

```
>>> import glob
>>> import os
>>> glob.glob(f'*{os.path.sep}')
['reviewer/', 'debian/', 'resources/', 'tests/']
```

But with `Path.glob` it's yiedling different results for the same pattern:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> [e.name for e in Path().glob(f'*{os.path.sep}')]
['reviewer', 'debian', '.coveragerc', '.gitignore', '.mypy_cache', '.venv', 'dev-requirements.txt', 'MANIFEST.in', 'tox.ini', 'setup.py', '.git', 'mypy.ini', '.idea', '.tox', 'resources', '.pyreview.ini', 'README.md', 'pytest.ini', '.coverage', 'requirements.txt', '.pytest_cache', 'tests']
```

Shouldn't both operations be equivalent? I know there are other ways to do what I'm trying to do, that's not my question; I want to know why are both operations yielding different results for the same glob pattern.

EDIT: same question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420100/how-to-prevent-pathlib-s-path-glob-from-returning-files-when-the-glob-ends-in-a)

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420100/how-to-prevent-pathlib-s-path-glob-from-returning-files-when-the-glob-ends-in-a has an answer that links to this open bug : https://bugs.python.org/issue22276

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, in [this issue#26096 Guido explained that consider it a feature](https://bugs.python.org/issue26096)

Comment: Oooh, I see. So these differences between `glob` and `Path.glob` are intended. It would be nice to have them listed somewhere. Thanks very much.

Comment: @buran That discussion is about dot files. Looking further on the issue with the final '/', there is a pull request to correct that, see https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/10349#pullrequestreview-171866354

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Indeed, closed as duplicate of the question you provided. Thanks very much.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, it clearly refers to both "files and directories". Yes, Guido mention just "dor files", but I think it's clear that he refers to both files and directories that start with dot. The pull request you link is about ending separator, not about the difference between between `glob.glob` and `pathlib.Path.glob` with respect to hidden files and directories.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, now I see what you mean.